# Yii2 submit modal form with ajax

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I've success create modal form, but I can't submit it with ajax. Everytime i click submit button it not stay in the index page but instead show `echo 1` from my Controller.

My controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Testing();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
       if($model->save()){
            echo 1;
        }else{
            echo 0;
        }
    }else{

        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My form

```
 <div class="testing-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName()]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'test')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<?php
$this->registerJS("

$('form#{$model->formName()}'.on('beforeSubmit', function(e)
{
    var \$form = $(this);
    $.post(
        \$form.attr('action'),
        \$form.serialize()
    )
        .done(function(result) {
        if(result == 1)
        {
            $(\$form).trigger('reset'); 
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#issuehrGrid'});
        }else
        {

            $('#message').html(result.message);
        }
        }).fail(function()
        {
            console.log('server error');
        })
    return false;
});"    
);     
?>
```

My view

```
<div class="report">
                    <h3>HR Issues</h3>
                     <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success modalButton']) ?>
                    <?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'issuehrGrid']); ?>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($dataProvider->models as $hr) {
                          ?>
                          <tr>

                            <td><?=$hr->test;?></td>

                          </tr>
                          <?php } ?>     
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
                </div>
```

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: because you are doing that, in your controller action code. dont know what you are up to or trying to do are you trying to submit the form and then display a message and stay on the same form? also you should just `return 1` rather than `echo 1`

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is that it would be showing you the blank page with `1` displayed in it is because after the first submission your Pjax grid is reloaded via the statement

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#issuehrGrid'});
```

and once reloaded your `beforeSubmit` event is not bound again to the form as the form `Html` is reloaded again and when you submit the form second time it just makes a simple form submit and displays the blank page with `1`, you need to use the `pjax:complete` event for the pjax, so that one the grid is reloaded your script binds the `beforeSubmit` event to the form again.

Also, you have a syntax error in your script which should be fixed. Change your script to the following

```
<?php
$formName = $model->formName();
$js = <<<JS
$(document).on("ready pjax:complete",function(){
    $('form#{$formName}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
        var \$form = $(this);
        $.post(
            \$form.attr('action'),
            \$form.serialize()
        ).done(function(result) {
            if(result == 1)
            {
                $(\$form).trigger('reset'); 
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#issuehrGrid'});
            }else
            {
                $('#message').html(result.message);
            }
            }).fail(function()
            {
                console.log('server error');
            })
        return false;
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJS(
    $js,
    \yii\web\View::POS_READY
);
?>
```

**UPDATE**

and dont forget to change the controller action code and change the `echo 1` to `return 1` and `echo 0` to `return 0`

Comment: THank you for helping me, i've tried to change my script like you said, but it still not working. Can I ask why use slash before variable like this `\$form`, i've never seen it before. And i use F12 to see source code, the slash is gone, just show `$form`, is that why it not working?

Comment: i have used the `heredoc` syntax to add the script and used `\\` to escape so it does not mistake it with php and force to parse it as a php variable and what is not working is there an error on console when you load the page or click on the button? @SaoHo

Comment: no, there are no error in the console, but it does have this warning `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: ok and when you click the submit does it show you any error on console or an ajax request? @SaoHo and you need to change the `echo 1;` to `return 1;` and `echo 0;` to `return 0` in the controller

Comment: no, this is console before click submit https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2019/06/18/image.png.
and this is after submit
https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2019/06/18/imagec89ea870d6e2aafe.png

Comment: I have change it to return when i see your comment :) not work though

Comment: can you show the view source from the bottom of the page before the cosing body tag where it shows the injected script we added in the view @SaoHo

Comment: here the script
https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2019/06/18/image0f0a10d99887ba65.png

Comment: have you provided the `id` to your form and is it same ? @SaoHo

Comment: yes, i have https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2019/06/18/imagee232341f08cb4d89.png

Comment: ok and how are you loading the modal window ? using js or `yii\bootstrap\Modal`

Comment: I used `yii\bootstrap\Modal`, with this script in the end of body

https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2019/06/18/Untitled-2.jpg